json.decoder.JSONDecodeError error python
I have an automation that runs and passes a JSON object to a Python script.
My objective is to read the JSON and convert it to a dictionary.
My JSON looks like this:
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Name": "baz",
            "File": "\\\\baz\\baz\\baz baz\\baz baz\\baz\\baz.xls"
        },
        {
            "Name": "bar",
            "File": "\\\\bar\\bar\\bar bar\\bar bar\\bar\\bar.csv"
        },
        {
            "Name": "foo",
            "File": "\\\\foo\\foo\\foo foo\\foo foo\\foo\\foo.csv"
        }
    ]
}

I need it to look like this:
{
  "foo" : "\\\\foo\\foo\\foo foo\\foo foo\\foo\\foo.csv",
  "bar" : "\\\\bar\\bar\\bar bar\\bar bar\\bar\\bar.csv",
  "baz" : "\\\\baz\\baz\\baz baz\\baz baz\\baz\\baz.xls"
}

I get this error with this piece of code:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 4 (char 6)

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    d = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    print(d)

This is what I pass to PowerShell:
@"
{
   {
    "Items": [
        {
            "Name": "baz",
            "File": "\\\\baz\\baz\\baz baz\\baz baz\\baz\\baz.xls"
        },
        {
            "Name": "bar",
            "File": "\\\\bar\\bar\\bar bar\\bar bar\\bar\\bar.csv"
        },
        {
            "Name": "foo",
            "File": "\\\\foo\\foo\\foo foo\\foo foo\\foo\\foo.csv"
        }
    ]
  }
}
"@

& $Python $Script $json

I printed sys.argv[1]:
    {Items:[{Name:foo,File:\\\\foo\\foo\\foo
    {Items:[{Name:foo,File:\\\\foo\\foo\\foo


json.loads(sys.argv[1]) would need sys.argv[1] being a JSON string (not a filename).

@tevemadar yes, I am passing a JSON string, not a file. And my JSON is valid so I am unsure why I am even getting the error.

Can you show exactly what your command line looks like? Passing a JSON structure (as a string) on a command line is going to be fraught with danger. You can start by print(sys.argv[1]) to see precisely what you're dealing with

your parameter is likely being stripped of double quotes but we can't know for sure unless you proved the exact command.

@SIGHUP i have updated the question for you. The thing is, it gets to my python script. So ther error is somewhere in my JSON I just do not know what is could be

@JonSG I provided the command for you

@JonSG yeah something is happening along the way becasue sys.argv[1] is not correct JSON

if you fix the nesting and escape the interal double quotes, you will be able to parse the arg as json.

import json

data = json.loads(original_json)

converted_data = {item["Name"]: item["File"] for item in data["Items"]}

converted_json = json.dumps(converted_data, indent=4)

print(converted_json)

Results from above Code

In what sense is this an answer to the question?

it answers the second part for me. The first part is solving the error

Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?
